# Git - Move feature branch ancestor pointer to latest commit on Master

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I'm following a workflow similar to the one describe by Scott Chacon in his [Pro Git](http://www.git-scm.com/book) book and illustrated in [3.2 Git Branching](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging).

I have created a branch (following along from Scott's example) `iss53`.  I've done work on that branch, but then need to switch gears and tackle a new issue.  I create branch `hotfix`.   Commits are added to `hotfix` and then merged back into `master`:

[image]

In Scott's example he doesn't need to take the commit from `hotfix` (C4) and apply it to `iss53`, but say I do.

**How can I update my feature branch so that it appears to have been branched from a later commit?**

Effectively, I want to update `iss53` so that it looks like this:

[image]

**Update:**

After researching this further, this article was what I was looking for to explain merging vs rebaseing: http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/08/21/merge-or-rebase/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html) which is explained after few pages in the same book.

```
$ git checkout iss53
$ git rebase master
```

Note that, rebase should be avoided if branch iss53 [is pushed to a remote that other people can access](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html#The-Perils-of-Rebasing).

Comment: If I rebase `master`, will that impact the next commit I make on `master`?  For example if I did what you propose, and then switched to the `master` branch and added commit `C5`.  I would still want `C5`'s ancestor to be `C4`, *not* `C3`.

Comment: No, it won't affect master. `C5`'s ancestor will be `C4` and `C3`'s ancestor will still be `C4`. If you want to make `C5` new ancestor of `C3` then you have to rebase again.

Comment: After some testing, you are right, it's exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks!